# How to select records (which have comma separated values) which do not have a value from the subquery returned?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

**UPDATE** SQL FIDDLE link https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9t63on5kYWUNrHqXkThb1P/4

Output should give only the following (row 2 of table1)

```
I0016,I0028,I0045,I0056,I0215,I0321,I0361,I0369,I0420
```

I should

```
select column1 from table1 
where <any comma separated value in column1> not in
(select col2 from table2 where col1 = 'e')
```

---

Preferable solution is native SQL, and nothing vendor specific. If necessary, spark sql functions help.

NOTE: I understand this is bad design, but this is out of my hands.

**NOTE** The table in FIDDLE is created using default setting of MySQL. I do not know how the tables are created at the backend. That is why I am specifying that this should not be vendor specific.

Comment: Do not store values as comma-delimited lists!  Fix your data structure!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know. I stated clearly in the question this is out of my hands. I did not design it, nor am I in a position to suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following correlated subquery works for my case. Can test it out in the fiddle above.

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where (
    select  t2.col2
    from    table2  as  t2
    where   t1.column1 like concat('%', t2.col2 ,'%')
    and t2.col1 = 'e'
    limit 1
    ) is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data structure!  Storing lists of values in a single column is not the appropriate way to store data in SQL.  You should be using a junction/association table.

You can do what you want using `not exists`:

```
select t1.column1
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where ',' || t1.column || ',' like '%,' || t2.value || ',%'
                 )
```

SparkSQL may also support `find_in_set()`, in which case you can do:

```
select t1.column1
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where find_in_set(t1.column, t2.value) > 0
                 )
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9t63on5kYWUNrHqXkThb1P/2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can you please explain where the subquery should be writting in your answer?

Comment: @scientific_explorer . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  This is describing the `where` clause that would seem to do what you want.

Comment: (1) I don't understand because in your answer you are selecting the column inside the subquery. I don't know whether or not that is possible. (2) Another thing which I am confused is the `s.value` what is value? (3) Is `s` an alias for the table used in my subquery?

Comment: @scientific_explorer . . . (1) Of course this is allowed.  It is called a correlated subquery.  `s` is an alias in the subquery.  You don't provide any table references.

Comment: Hi I have updated the question to include sample tables. Can you please update your answer accordingly? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi, after your update, the first query does not work on my fiddle to give me the desired output. It shows `There are no results to be displayed.`

Comment: @scientific_explorer . . . First, your db<>fiddle is set to MySQL where `||` does not necessarily mean string concatenation.  Second, your two examples each have an overlap in `table2` -- `'I0045'` and `'I0046'`.

Comment: Please look at the question again. I have updated it to include **only** the fiddle. Like I said earlier, I do not know why it was designed, or what db is used to design this. So I cannot randomly pick any version/vendor on my fiddle to create an example. I picked the default setting for the example table.

Comment: I edited your first code to use a `concat` for the `mySQL`, yet it does not give any output.